# Perl hit counter for multiple ranges, options in other languages?

Tags: perl

Coming back for your advice. I have written a perl script that counts the number of hits of specific numbers into user-defined bins. For example, this is my data file:

```
12
14
15
20
21
```

And I want to know how many hits I have in the following ranges:

```
1-19
20-29
30-39
```

So results would be like

```
1-19    3
20-29   2
30-39   0
```

I have done such a thing by fist saving my data into a hash (datahash), then saving my ranges into another hash (rangehash), and then basically going over all the data points in datahash and checking that the value falls within the ranges of the rangehash.

The problem is that for each datapoint in datahash, I loop through all the rangehash values and exit once I find the range where the datapoint falls. This is good for few data points, but now I'm having files with at least 2 million datapoints and 50,000 ranges, so looping through all of that just takes forever.

I was wondering if anyone would have  better solution rather than just looping through the whole thing. Suggestions for other languages are well received!!!

Best,

Sakti

Comment: Crossposted at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1048441.

Answer (score 5):

The following will be super fast, although it assumes zero won't occur:

```
my @buckets = (0) x 4;
++$buckets[ $_ / 10 ] while <>:
print " 1-19: ".( $buckets[0] + $buckets[1] )."\n";
print "20-29: $buckets[2]\n";
print "30-39: $buckets[3]\n";
```

The following more general solution might actually be faster:

```
use List::Util qw( sum );
++$counts[$_] while <>:
print " 1-19: ".( sum 0, @counts[ 1..19] )."\n";
print "20-29: ".( sum 0, @counts[20..29] )."\n";
print "30-39: ".( sum 0, @counts[30..39] )."\n";
```

Comment: Initializing an array is redundant. `++` will automatically translate undef to 0. Also, `map 0, 0..3` aka `(0) x 4`. You probably also did not mean to use `%` but `/`.

Comment: @TLP, It's not redundant as it prevents attempts to print undef.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method would likely be to add the numbers up with a hash, then sum up the hash slice for the corresponding range. You can also use an array instead of a hash, since you can use numbers as indexes. This can potentially create very large empty hashes which is wasteful, but it simplifies the key generation, as bad indexes will issue warnings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'sum';

my %nums;
while (<DATA>) {
    s/\D+//g;     # remove junk
    $nums{$_}++;  # count number
}
my $low = 1;
for my $high (qw(19 29 39)) {
    my $sum =  sum(0,                      # to avoid undef return value
                   grep defined,           # avoid uninitialized warnings
                   @nums{$low .. $high});  # hash slice for our range
    print "$low - $high : $sum\n";
    $low = $high + 1;                      # set new low range
}

__DATA__
12
14
15
20
21
```

**Output:**

```
1 - 19 : 3
20 - 29 : 2
30 - 39 : 0
```

Comment: Thanks TLP! Will test this out and check how it diminishes computation times, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*This only applies to user defined bins, i.e. ones that cannot easily be calculated as `int($x / 100)*100` or the like.*

There was a similar question lately here or on perlmonks (which I cannot find easily), and the best answer IMO was "sort bins' upper bounds, then use binary search".

For 50K bins, this is about 16 `if`s per data point which is probably ok (certainly not "forever").

Depending on the data, some caching may be applied to achieve further speed up. E.g. one could round data to 1/1000 of expected interval (last bin - 1st bin) and only check bins that cover this part. (I just made this up, but it may work. Or not.).